# Extracting title from HTML not working

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm performing some text analytics on a large number of novels downloaded from Gutenberg. I want to keep as much metadata as a I can, so I'm downloading as html then later converting to text. My problem is extracting the metadata from the html files, in particular, the title of each novel.

As of now, I'm using BeautifulSoup to generate the text files and extract the title. For an example text of Jane Eyre, my code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

### Opens html file
html = open("filepath/Jane_Eyre.htm")

### Cleans html file
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

title_data = soup.title.string
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

The `title` tag is definitely there in the original html; when I open the file this is what I see in the first few lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII" />
<title>Jane Eyre</title>
<style type="text/css">
```

Does anyone have any suggestion as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I am seeing a lot of problems with BeautifulSoup lately. Maybe it's just me but I like implementing scraping stuff myself. Suggest you to build your scrapper with `re` regex library for python

Answer (score 1):

Try this One :

```
title_data = soup.find(".//title").text
```

or

```
title_data = soup.findtext('.//title')
```

Comment: Still getting the same error message using either of these approaches. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use other BS4 methods, like this one:

```
title_data = soup.find('title').get_text()
```

Comment: Can you please try to `print soup` after you initialize BeautifulSoup, you should get the whole HTML document there.

Comment: Did that, but it's huge––whole novel here. Can't seem to access the start, if you mean for me to check for the <title> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `html.parser` instead of `lxml`

e.g:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

### Opens html file
html = open("filepath/Jane_Eyre.htm")

### Cleans html file
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

title_data = soup.title.string
```

Your `html` tag has a namespace, so if you try to parse it with `lxml` you should respect the namespaces.

Comment: Still no joy I'm afraid: keep getting the "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'" reply even when the parser is changed. Thanks all the same!

Comment: Output won't change by changing the parser. Furthermore, lxml is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `lxml`?

```
from lxml import html
page = html.fromstring(source_string)
title = page.xpath("/title/text()")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following approach works to extract the titles from html file of Gutenberg ebooks.

```
>>> from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/subject/99'
>>> req = Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
>>> webpage = urlopen(req).read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
>>> required = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "title"})
>>> x1 = []
>>> for i in required:
...     x1.append(i.get_text())
...
>>> for i in x1:
...     print(i)
...
Sort Alphabetically
Sort by Release Date
Great Expectations
Jane Eyre: An Autobiography
Les Misérables
Oliver Twist
Anne of Green Gables
David Copperfield
The Secret Garden
Anne of the Island
Anne of Avonlea
A Little Princess
Kim
Anne's House of Dreams
Heidi
The Mysteries of Udolpho
Of Human Bondage
The Secret Garden
Daddy-Long-Legs
Les misérables Tome I: Fantine (French)
Jane Eyre
Rose in Bloom
Further Chronicles of Avonlea
The Children of the New Forest
Oliver Twist; or, The Parish Boy's Progress. Illustrated
The Personal History of David Copperfield
Heidi
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

OP here. For anyone coming to this looking for a solution, here's what I did as a workaround. It's a bit kludgy, but it got me where I needed to go:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

### Opens html file
html = open("/filepath/Jane_Eyre.htm")

### Cleans html file
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


title = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>',soup.get_text())

print(title)
```

I don't know why the title tags work in the get_text() version and not in the html; I also recognise that regular expressions are suboptimal for html parsing. But it resolved the issue for me.