# Getting clean text file from BeautifulSoup html parser

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm having a lot of teething problems with BeautifulSoup while trying to perform text analytics on Project Gutenberg files (see here for [yesterday's solved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035683/extracting-title-from-html-not-working/46049877#46049877)). I nearly have all my code in order, but there's one last problem baffling me: how to get a clean text file written after I've eliminated some redundant text from the version cleaned by BeautifulSoup. Let me explain:

Step 1: I extract the text minus the html junk while recording the text title:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

### Opens saved html file
html = open("/filepath/Jane_Eyre_Test.htm")

### Cleans html file
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


title = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>',soup.get_text())
```

Step 2: Get rid of the boilerplate Gutenberg license text so it doesn't mess up the analysis:

```
s1 = '***START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK '+title[0].upper()+'***'

s2 = '***END OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK '+title[0].upper()+'***'

main_text = soup.get_text()[(soup.get_text().index(s1)+len(s1)):soup.get_text().index(s2)]
```

Step 3: Open text file to write the results into:

```
#### Opens blank text file
f = open('filepath/'+titles[0]+'.txt', 'w')
f.write(main_text)
```

Now, here's the problem: when I do this, the resulting text file is full of formatting tags, e.g.:

> </pre>
>   <p><a name="startoftext"></a></p> <p>Transcribed from the 1897 Service
>   &amp; Paton edition by David Price, email
>   ccx074@pglaf.org</p>

But when I try to clean it using Beautiful soup as follows,

```
main_text1 = BeautifulSoup(main_text, 'html.parser')
f.write(main_text1.get_text())
```

the result is not much better.

```
</pre> <p><a name="startoftext"></a></p> <p>Transcribed from the 1897
Service &amp; Paton edition by David Price, email ccx074@pglaf.org</p>
```

This is despite the fact that

```
f.write(soup.get_text())
```

produces a perfectly formatted text file. I suspect that I'm missing some crucial difference here between text formatting and html formatting; if so, any instruction appreciated. And of course, any solutions for getting rid of the text formatting tags would be even more appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to change your parser to lxml or html5lib?

Comment: Just tried it, only to get:

"FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib.parser. Do you need to install a parser library?"

A pip install of html5lib and lxml said they're installed already.

Comment: Yes you need to install html5lib by `pip install html5lib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approach, the `get_text()` should work fine on a `soup` object:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

with open('Jane_Eyre_Test.htm') as f_jane_html:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_jane_html, "html.parser")

a = soup.find('a', attrs={"name" : "startoftext"})
text = a.parent.parent.get_text()

start = re.escape("***START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK JANE EYRE***")
end = re.escape("***END OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK")
text = re.search('{}(.*){}'.format(start, end), text, re.S).group(1)

with open('Jane_Eyre.txt', 'w') as f_jane_text:
    f_jane_text.write(text)
```

This would give you a file starting and ending as follows:

```
Transcribed from the 1897 Service & Paton edition by David

Price, email ccx074@pglaf.org
JANE EYRE

AN AUTOBIOGRAPHY
by
.
.
.
I come quickly!’ and hourly I more eagerly

respond,—‘Amen; even so come, Lord

Jesus!’”
```

The HTML to test this on was taken from [Jane Eyre, by Charlotte Bronte](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1260/1260-h/1260-h.htm)

The test file was created as follows:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1260/1260-h/1260-h.htm")

with open('Jane_Eyre_Test.htm', 'w') as f_jane_eyre:
    f_jane_eyre.write(r.content)
```

Comment: This really is an excellent––and fast!––solution. It's also exactly the html source I'm using. However, when I run it I get an AttributeError after 

`text = a.parent.parent.get_text()`

Namely:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'`

Could this possibly be caused by the fact that I've downloaded the html file beforehand rather than accessed it via URL?

Comment: I used `requests.get()` to download the HTML from that link and wrote it straight to a file. It would imply your HTML is a slightly different structure. You could try `a.parent.get_text()`

Comment: No luck with `a.parent.get_text()` I'm afraid. If it was just the occasional file I'd also use `requests.get()`; however, I'm doing a big assay of Gutenberg, and the [wget](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg%3aInformation_About_Robot_Access_to_our_Pages#Getting_All_EBook_Files) interface they prefer only allows for direct downloads to disk.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how to use `requests.get()` to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a clean text file written after eliminating some redundant text. You [follow from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035683/extracting-title-from-html-not-working/46049877#46049877/%22see%20from%20this%22)

```
>>> with open("Book_titles.txt", "w") as file:
...     for line in x1:
...             file.writelines(line)
...             file.writelines('\n')
...
>>>
```